# DateTime modify string for first day of current year

Tags: php, datetime

im looking for the DateTime modify String for the first day of the year (now 1. January 2011). I tried the following:

```
<?php

$time = new DateTime();

// works as expected, the first day of the current month
$time->modify('first day of this month');
echo $time->format('c')."\n";


// this doesn't work. I also tried several other ways
$time->modify('first day of january');
echo $time->format('c')."\n";

>
```

I know there are other ways to retrieve the date, but I search an string for DateTime->modify() no other solution.

Comment: I think you found a bug. I have php 5.3.3 and with the use of "first day of" or "last day of" and a month + year it doesn't work. It simply give you the first/last day of the current(or previous changed with modify) month.

Comment: Yeah, you are right its a bug. I think this ist the Problem: "5.3.6    Absolute date/time statements now take effect." - Previously, only relative parts were used. From: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php .Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Well, in this case my answer is still correct but for php version >= 5.3.6 ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should specify the year too, as you can see in this example:

```
"first day of January 2008"
```

from the [official doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

**Update: It works on php version >= 5.3.6**

Comment: Tried it but doesn't work: 
  
$time->modify('first day of january 2011'); 
echo $time->format('c')."\n";  


$time->modify('first day of january this year');  
echo $time->format('c')."\n";

Answer (score 8):

On v5.5.6

> echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of January this year'));

Result: `2013-01-01`

Answer (score 2):

To get the day of the week for the first of the year 
or the first day of the month

```
<?php
//This is for a given month 
$m="May";
   // this id for this month
  //$m=date('F');
  //if you want the day of Sunday instead D use lower case l
  echo date('D', strtotime('first day of January this year'));
 echo "<br>". date("D", strtotime('first day of'. $m ));
?>
```

Result Wed For May with D
Result Wednesday with l

Answer (score 1):

This work for me (PHP 5.6 - not tested on older version)... as we talk for `DateTime` object

```
//Get current datetime
$now = new DateTime();
$now->modify('first day of January this year');

echo $now->format('Y-m-d');
// Print (current year)-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo (new DateTime())->modify('first day of January this year')->format('Y-m-d');
```